# What's the purpose of this code that catches error, rollbacks the transaction and then reraises the same error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I've inherited some piece of magic boilerplate code that presumably deals with [*transaction count mismatch*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315836/tsql-try-catch-transaction-error-handling-transaction-count-mismatch) problem when the stored procedure is being called from inside another one that has a transaction opened.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_My]
AS
    SET XACT_ABORT ON
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @starttrancount int
    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT @starttrancount = @@TRANCOUNT
        IF @starttrancount = 0
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

        -- some actually useful SQL code here

        IF @starttrancount = 0 
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 AND @starttrancount = 0 
              ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage nvarchar(400);
        SELECT @ErrorMessage = error_message();

        RAISERROR ( @ErrorMessage, 16, 0 );
    END CATCH
```

The problem is I don't really get the intent behind this code. I mean if there's an error in this stored procedure it should rollback the top level transaction anyway and the nested transactions should just be ignored and their changes rolled back just as well.

What does this code do and why?

Comment: Let's say your application code calls your procedure, and your procedure fails. What do you think the procedure should signal back after rollback? I think it should scream error. Thus the RAISERROR.

Comment: @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric: I actually expected the error to bubble up while the transaction is being rolled back.

Comment: There is no rethrowing (aka exception bubbling) in older SQL Server. It hasn't been introduced before SQL Server 2012. The code was probably written on the older RDBMS.

Comment: @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric: Whatever. Suppose there was no try-catch in there, just a commit at the end of the procedure. Suppose there would be an error somewhere in the middle. Wouldn't the error bubble up to the user and the transaction rolled back?

Comment: It depends on the calling environment. I guess there is no point of doing that if you are sure you will encapsulate everything with one and one transaction only. However, what if there is a SQL Server job that occasionally calls that sproc and it doesn't use a transaction? And you don't have a control over it?

Comment: @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric: Okay, suppose there's no outer transaction indeed and there's just a `BEGIN TRAN`-`COMMIT` in there (no try-catch) and there's an error. Won't the error bubble up and transaction be rolled back?

Comment: You are right, in that case the exception would bubble up and whatever kind of database access layer would be allowed to consume it. However, this code is NOT written with that kind of scenario in mind. Instead it allows for transaction nesting, and that is sometimes a requirement. If you don't need that, use a simple transaction begin-commit-rollback functionality. Of course, if you need your T-SQL code to react in case of an error, use try/catch as well.

Comment: @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric: This doesn't explain why a try-catch-raise thing is needed. Okay, transactions are nested and one of them raises an error - why would try-catch-raise be needed instead of just letting the error bubble up and having the transaction rolled back?